# Accept case-insensitive URL or redirect to "correct" URL?

Tags: apache, http, rest, url, url-rewriting

Let's say that I have a web app that responds to URLs in the format `/entities/{entityKey}`. In my access logs, I find people visiting both `/entities/KEY1` which is how app URLs are generated, as well as the lower case version of `/entities/key1`. Currently key1 will throw a 404 not found error due to route requirements.

My question is, would you:

1. Use URL re-writing to re-write key to uppercase.
2. Create 302 redirects from lowercase to uppercase?
3. Have the application convert to uppercase and handle requests in a case-insensitive fashion

Comment: See also on Webmasters: [How to handle URLs that differ in case-sensitivity and show same content](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/54790/17633)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most users these days expect URLs to be case-insensitive. I would have the app silently handle the conversion in the background. I don't see it being worth the extra request time to issue a redirect.

If SEO is a concern, then you can use the [rel="canonical"](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en&ei=DjR8Ut2aIcbHrQeBy4AI&usg=AFQjCNGBQfJk8au-wpmiE8jFAZ2vJ6ZAzQ&sig2=4wl36HXSeEZnnp-C26kJZw&bvm=bv.56146854,d.bmk) meta tag to let google/other search engines know which URL you want to appear in search results.